# 3 docs in Docusign envelope, only one gets delivered

Tags: docusignapi

I can't figure out why the only document that gets delivered here is the first one. The roles on doc 1 are : buyer, seller, doc2 has seller and lawyer, doc3 has buyer and seller. I purposely left off a template role for lawyer. Here is what the envelope definition looks like:

```
 {
  "documents": [
    {
      "documentId": "1",
      "name": "Here is document one of the test.docx",
      "fileExtension": "docx",
      "documentFields": [
        {
          "name": "Doc1Info",
          "value": "here is doc1 info"
        }
      ],
      "documentBase64": [bytearray]
    },
    {
      "documentId": "2",
      "name": "Here is document two of the test",
      "fileExtension": "docx",
      "documentFields": [
        {
          "name": "Doc2Info",
          "value": "here is doc2 info"
        }
      ],
      "documentBase64": [bytearray]
    },
    {
      "documentId": "3",
      "name": "Here is document three of the test",
      "fileExtension": "docx",
      "documentFields": [
        {
          "name": "Doc3Info",
          "value": "here is doc3 info"
        }
      ],
      "documentBase64": [bytearray]
    }
  ],
  "customFields": {
    "textCustomFields": [
      {
        "name": "My file id",
        "value": "1823456"
      }
    ]
  },
  "eventNotification": {
    "url": "http://requestb.in/opiu2bop",
    "loggingEnabled": "true",
    "requireAcknowledgment": "true",
    "envelopeEvents": [
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Delivered"
      },
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Completed"
      },
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Declined"
      },
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Voided"
      },
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Sent"
      }
    ],
    "useSoapInterface": "false",
    "includeCertificateWithSoap": "false",
    "signMessageWithX509Cert": "false",
    "includeDocuments": "false",
    "includeEnvelopeVoidReason": "false",
    "includeTimeZone": "true",
    "includeSenderAccountAsCustomField": "true",
    "includeDocumentFields": "true",
    "includeCertificateOfCompletion": "false"
  },
  "templateId": "xxxx-ad34-4a2e-a375-069ce2df630c",
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "email": "KathyGilbert11@xxx.com",
      "roleName": "##Buyer1",
      "name": "Kathy Gilbert",
      "routingOrder": "1"
    },
    {
      "email": "KathyLangdon1@xxx.com",
      "roleName": "##Seller1",
      "name": "Kathy Langdon",
      "routingOrder": "2"
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent",
  "emailSubject": "Please sign the following document at 9:49 AM"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with roles. Since you are specifying "ServerTemplate" in your request  along with some additional documents. This is considered as a compositeTemplate.

In a single Composite Template you can only overlay ONE document. You will have to use multiple CompositeTemplates in your request to overlay all the three documents.

Here is a working code which overlays multiple documents on a server template. I have simplified your example below(removed connect & custom field related info). It should still work if you add that information back.

Tip: If you want to retain the documents in your server Template, you can move the Document(documentId:1) specified in the first Composite Template( ID:1) to the second CompositeTemplate (ID:2). The final envelope will have 3 more documents in addition to the documents on your serverTemplate

```
 {
     "emailSubject": "Testing multiple docs",
     "status": "sent",
     "compositeTemplates": [
         {
             "compositeTemplateId": "1",
             "serverTemplates": [
                 {
                     "sequence": "1",
                     "templateId": "XXXXXX-2f8a-4cfc-907b-4c84cb523426"
                 }
             ],
             "inlineTemplates": [
                 {
                     "sequence": "2",

                     "recipients": {
                         "signers": [
                             {
                                 "name": "Byer One",
                                 "email": "buyerone@acme.com",
                                 "roleName": "##Buyer1",
                                 "recipientId": "1",
                                 "routingOrder": "1",

                             }
                         ]
                     }
                 }
             ],
             "document": {
                 "documentId": "1",
                 "name": "Here is document one of the test",
                 "fileExtension": "docx",
                 "documentBase64": "[Bytes Removed]"
             }
         },
         {
             "compositeTemplateId": "2",
             "inlineTemplates": [
                 {
                    "sequence" : "3",
                     "documents": [
                         {
                             "documentId": "2",
                             "name": "Here is document two of the test",
                             "fileExtension": "docx",
                             "documentBase64": "[Bytes Removed]"

                         },
                         {
                             "documentId": "3",
                             "name": "Here is document three of the test",
                             "fileExtension": "docx",
                             "documentBase64": "[Bytes Removed]"
                         }
                     ]

                 }
             ]
         }
     ]
 }
```

Comment: I didn't specify a composite template for this. I'm just using the one server template. Does docusign assume that since I'm using a server template that it is also a composite template?

Comment: Yes since you are using a serverTemplate it is considered as  a single CompositeTemplate. So the same rules of a compositeTemplate apply.

Comment: I see. I don't think that info is anywhere in their documentation. Thank you for the insight. I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Please refer to this documentation for applying templates. See "Using Templates" & "Composite Templates" sections. https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/